# when opening sample app get this solution requires xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm new to xamarin. I downloaded tasky sample but I have this message in xamarin studio why ?

Is it this sample requires paid version of xamarin which supports form ?

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Forms are not part of [Starter edition(free)](https://store.xamarin.com/). But you can use 1 month trail.

Comment: yes but the message is about xamarin.android, is xamarin.forms included in xamarin.android, is the official tasky sample requires xamarin.forms ?

Comment: You need Xamarin.Android in all cases(also for Xamarin.Forms). There are two Tasky apss. One is Tasky which does not require Xamarin.Forms and TaskyPro which is written with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: But why it didn't get install then ? How to install it then ?

Comment: It's hard to fully understand what problem is... join this JabbR channel so we can clarify what is the problem ;) https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/Xamarin because this comments are taking too long :)